# PhoneGap - device sleep mode event

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I am developing an application with Phonegap for iOS and Android. I need to execute some instructions when the device comes back from sleep mode.

The "resume" event works for this, but is is also fired when the user opens another app, and in my case, the instructions have to be executed only when the device comes back from sleep mode.

Is there a way to do this ?

Comment: "but is is also fired when the user opens another app" are u mean to say when you resume from another app to ur app?

Comment: yes, when the app is hasn't been closed and when you touch the icon app to display it.

Comment: I am facing the same issue, have you finally found a solution? Thank you

Comment: I don't work with PhoneGap anymore. I hadn't find any solution but maybe plugins exist now...